# Disable NancyFx module discovery

Tags: unit-testing, nancy

Is there a way to disable the module discovery and explicitly specify what module classes to use?

This is for test performance reasons. The project states that:

*"[scanning] it is part of the startup of any Nancy application and is only performed once and the information is then cached."*

and that's dandy, but it seems every unit test also does this global scan, and then it's not fast enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information is for application runtime, not testing. When you are testing a Nancy application, using our [testing features](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Testing-your-application) such as the `Browser` class Nancy will require you to be explicit about this

You do this by using a combination of the `Module(...)`, `Module<T>()` or `Modules(...)` methods during the `Browser` / `ConfigurableBootstrapper` setup

The one time that the testing features would use all modules during testing is if you've explicitly called `AllDiscoveredModules` instead

Comment: Thanks! Works great. This post shows how it's done in more detail: http://www.marcusoft.net/2013/01/NancyTesting2.html